# Help needed with finding power series, convergence radius, and interval

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, summation

I am currently struggling with finding the power series, convergence radius, and interval for the following functions:

a) $f(x)=\frac{2}{1-x}$

b) $f(x)=2 \ln (1-x)$

Here is what I have attempted so far:

a) For function a), I started by using the formula for the geometric series to write:

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$$

Then, I multiplied both sides by 2 to get:

$$\frac{2}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2x^n$$

This gives me the power series for $f(x)$, but I am unsure how to find the convergence radius and interval.

b) For function b), I used the power series expansion for $\ln (1-x)$, which is:

$$\ln (1-x) = - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}$$

Then, I multiplied both sides by 2 to get:

$$2 \ln (1-x) = -2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}$$

Again, I am not sure how to find the convergence radius and interval for this function.

Could someone please help me with finding the convergence radius and interval for these functions? Any explanation or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) $R$ of these two power series is the same (since one is, up to sign, the derivative of the other one), and for the first one ([geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)) it is well-known: $R=1.$ The interval is $(-R,R).$ More precisely, both are abolutely convergent on this open interval. The geometric series is trivially divergent for $x=\pm R.$

Comment: @Anne Bauval I see, so since the power series for the two functions are related to each other by a constant multiple, they will have the same radius of convergence. That makes sense.  I also appreciate the reminder that the radius of convergence for a geometric series is 1. Therefore, for function a), the radius of convergence is 1 and the interval of convergence is (-1,1). And since the power series for function a) converges absolutely for all $x$ in the interval (-1,1), the interval of convergence is also the interval of absolute convergence.

Comment: As for function b), since it is the derivative of the power series for function a), the radius of convergence will also be 1. Therefore, the interval of convergence is (-1,1). And since the power series for function b) converges absolutely for all $x$ in the open interval (-1,1), we can say that the interval of absolute convergence for function b) is also (-1,1).  Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Yes, and a finer result (not deducible from the previous ones) is that the series for $\ln(1-x)$ is divergent for $x=1$ but semi-convergent (alternate) for $x=-1.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for sharing that additional information about the series for ln(1-x)! It is true that the series for ln(1-x) is divergent when x=1, since the terms of the series do not approach zero as n approaches infinity. However, I was not aware that the series is semi-convergent (alternating) when x=-1. That's an interesting result! I can see that this is the case by plugging in x=-1 into the power series expansion for ln(1-x) that I found earlier: $$\ln(1-x) = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}$$ When x=-1, we get: $$\ln2 = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$

Comment: "The series for $\ln(1-x)$ is divergent when $x=1$" not because "the terms of the series do not approach zero as n approaches infinity" (they do!) but because it is (up to sign) the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)). Note also that the last equation in your comment is not obvious. You can use [Taylor-Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) to prove it.

Comment: @AnneBauval You are absolutely right that the series for ln(1-x) is not divergent because the terms do not approach zero as n approaches infinity. Rather, it is because the series is (up to sign) the harmonic series, which is known to be divergent. As for the last equation in my previous comment, you are correct that it is not obvious.

Comment: One way to prove it rigorously is by using Taylor's theorem with the Lagrange remainder. Specifically, we can write: $$\ln(1-x) = -\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{x^n}{n} - \frac{x^N}{N} \cdot \frac{1}{1-t} \cdot \frac{(-x)^N}{N}$$ for some $t$ between $x$ and 0, since the Lagrange remainder term for the Taylor series expansion of ln(1-x) is given by: $$R_N(x) = \frac{(-x)^N}{N(1-t)^{N+1}}$$ Taking the limit as $N \rightarrow \infty$, we have: $$\ln2 = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$ which is the well-known result for the alternating harmonic series.